# Any way to make the Flash Builder's Mobile Debugger window a bit smaller?

Tags: android, apache-flex, debugging, mobile, flash-builder

The window for Flash Builder's mobile device emulator (in AIR) seems to be a bit too tall for a resolution running 1280x800. Is there a way to make it run smaller? 1280x800 is the highest resolution set-able on the laptop being used to develop for it.

See the screenshot: [image: http://i.imgur.com/XVONu.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that I can think of to change the device emulator resolution is from the **Run Configuration** window.

Your Run button has a small down arrow next to it. If you press it you'll see it. There you should have **Launch method** with two radio buttons and a drop-down. You can select from the drop-down to emulate a device that has a smaller resolution, like HTC Hero or iPhone 3GS. To see all the available options click the **Configure** button. There you can also add a new device with a custom resolution that fits better on your screen.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: THANK YOU. I never saw HTC Hero on the list but I managed to get by with configuring a custom device that I called "Android Test". Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Really you're talking about the mobile device emulator; not a debug window.

Really the only thing you can do is increase your screen resolution or run things on an actual device.  Getting an external monitor that supports larger resolutions is an easy way to "extend" your laptop's resolution.

I suspect there is a formal feature request for this in the Flex bug base, because it has come up before in other forums.

Comment: Changed the definition above. And are there any hacks that can be done to achieve such? Aside from getting an external monitor or testing on an actual device? Googling for it keeps sending me irrelevant links.

Comment: In case my answer was unclear, I do not know of any hacks to make the emulator window "Smaller" on your screen.

Comment: Alright thanks. I'll keep the question open for 1 more day to see if anyone can nail it. :) If not then I guess yours is the closest to an answer I can get. :)

Comment: I'd love nothing better than to have someone come along and prove me wrong.